# is "ConnectionMultiplexer.IsConnected" expensive?

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

In my caching `AddItem` and `GetItem` methods, I check if the connection to redis is alive or not before proceeding, is `ConnectionMultiplexer.IsConnected` an expensive method call? or should I just catch an exception and reconnect in that case?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking at [ConnectionMultiplexer.IsConnected](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/dcf1798775b409666ba3179fd54518baa1349b49/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/ConnectionMultiplexer.cs#L1753) code:

```
public bool IsConnected
{
    get
    {
        var tmp = serverSnapshot;
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.Length; i++)
            if (tmp[i].IsConnected) return true;
        return false;
    }
}
```

It seems like all work done here is going through server endpoints to see whether there is at-least one server endpoint connected.

Looking at [ServerEndPoint.IsConnected](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/567cdf73fc61930f4c164795306f35e517a2f342/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/ServerEndPoint.cs#L85) code:

```
public bool IsConnected
{
    get
    {
        var tmp = interactive;
        return tmp != null && tmp.IsConnected;
    }
}
```

All work done here is returning interactive(of type PhysicalBridge) IsConnected value.

Looking at [PhysicalBridge.IsConnected](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/blob/567cdf73fc61930f4c164795306f35e517a2f342/StackExchange.Redis/StackExchange/Redis/PhysicalBridge.cs#L70) code:

```
public bool IsConnected => state == (int)State.ConnectedEstablished;
```

You can see all work done here is return whether two int's are equal.

So it seems like very little work is done calling ConnectionMultiplexer.IsConnected property.